# ASP.Net Core: How to add a custom configuration loaded via FileStream and Deserialization to the IConfiguration

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I have a custom configuration XML file came with an SDK. I like to use that file without modifying in order to avoid refactoring all the SDK files dependent on.

I tried with `.addXMLFile`. But, apparently the XML file is not compatible with that.
And then I converted the XML file into json and tried with `.addJsonFile`. But, it didn't work either, I mean there were several errors complaining about null objects. I don't want to ask on this part, maybe on another topic later on.

Therefore, I've decided to use the proven existing working file loading (`StreamReader`) and mapping (`Deserializing`) to my custom class(es).

So far so good. But, at this point, I am not sure how to proceed and append this custom configuration to the `IConfiguration` in `Startup`.

At least I tried that;

```
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      ...
      ICustomConfiguration settings = null;
      settings = Settings.LoadFromFile("MyCustomConfig.xml"); // settings shows proper structure and data after loading here.
      _configuration.Bind("CustomConfigurationFromFile", (CustomConfigurationFromFile)settings);
      services.AddSingleton(settings);
      ...
    }
```

Although this doesn't give any error or complain I couldn't see my custom configuration within the collections of the `_configuration`. Either there is a silence error during binding or my understanding from `bind` is not accurate.

Any input highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try options pattern feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0

With this you can inject e.g. an `IOptions<YourCustomConfig>` instance where it is needed.

Comment: Yes, in fact that I've started with that options pattern. But, although `.addXmlFile` loads up the file into `IConfiguration`, assigning it to my `CustomConfigurationFromFile` in my service class (controller) causes incompatibilities. This `private readonly CustomConfigurationFromFile_customSettings;` and `IOptions<CustomConfigurationFromFile> options,` and `_customSettings = options;` leads to `object not set to an instance of an object` due to complex Getter and Setter in class properties. This is why I said that "I don't want to ask on this part, maybe on another topic later on."